# Serverless framework: how to specify a c++ lambda function with provided deployment package

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless

I have followed the guide in https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-c-lambda-runtime/ to package my c++ lambda function into a zip file. The zip file has the contents: 
function.zip
  bin
     function
  lib
     many .so files, etc.
  bootstrap

In the guide the lambda is deployed using the `aws lambda create-function` with the handler specified to be the same as the zip file name.

I would like to configure this lambda function in my serverless.yml and deploy it with the rest of my lambdas. I am not sure what the handler field below should be and using the zip file name didn't work out.

```
functions:  
  function:
    runtime: provided
    package:
      include: 
        - function.zip
    handler: function 
    events:
      - http:
          path: function
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam
```

When I run `serverless deploy -v` I get warnings like:

> Serverless:  WARNING: Entry for function@function could not be
>   retrieved. Please check your service config if you want to use
>   lib.entries.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any documentation from serverless.com that they support C and C++ (while AWS Lambda might do), I have asked about it now so that we can know:

https://forum.serverless.com/t/c-and-c-support/8045

("Supports Node.js, Python, Java, Go, C#, Ruby, Swift, Kotlin, PHP, Scala, & F#") but if you want to try then I think that you should try some other name than "function" for your function. I did not try this at home but all examples use some other name than "function" because that word might be reserved.

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources/

If that still won't work, check your path to your code and maybe you also want to set up everything up with a CI/CD pipeline with GitLab for example. That's how I do it.

Comment: I used a different name than "function". I have no knowledge of Gitlab CI/CD... but  I will see if it can help